# Matplotlib monitor - plot values from table every X seconds

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm new to python and matplotlib and need a few pointers. I'm trying to write a monitor that queries a table and plots the results. from the table I can extract a timestamp I'd like to use for the X axis and a #of seconds I'd like to use for the Y value (number of packets sent). I'm not sure where "i" is populated for the animate function. My plot comes up but is empty. I'm not sure what ax.set_xlim should be set to and finally how do I get the date/timestamp to show up on the x-axis?
Im trying to modify the following example:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(ylim=(0, 45))
line, = ax.plot([], [], lw=5)

def init():
    line.set_data([], [])
    return line,

def animate(i):
    x,y,dk=getData()
    line.set_data(x, y)
    return line,

def Execute():
    #anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init, frames=200, interval=200, blit=True)
    anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init, frames=200, interval=2000)
    plt.show()
    return(anim)

def getDataSql(sql):
    ... run sql
    return(rl)

def getData():
    ...format return for getDataSql 
    ...return X ex(2013-04-12 18:18:24) and Y ex(7.357) (both are lists)
    return(X,Y,xy)

x=Execute()
```

Comment: and what exactly is your question? do you find anything wrong with the example? you don't know how to modify it? on which part? why?

Comment: Can you edit this to only include the relevant code?  We don't need to see your sql code (which we can't run any way), replace it with a stub function that returns fake data.

Answer (score 1):

```
def Execute():
    anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init, frames=200, interval=2000, blit=True)
    plt.show() 
    return anim

anim = Execute()
```

If you don't return the `anim` object (which has all the timers ect) in it, it gets garbage collected when `Execute` returns, which deletes all those objects, and hence your animation does not run.

You might also test using `blit=False`, it is a bit slower (which isn't an issue as you are updating ever 2s), but it is a bit less fincky to get working right.

Also try

```
ax.get_xaxis().set_major_locator(matplotlib.dates.AutoDateLocator())
ax.get_xaxis().set_major_formatter(matplotlib.dates.AutoDateFormatter())
```

before you run anything.

Comment: no joy. Updated the code in the first post.  the first value in the list x is 'datetime.datetime(2013, 4, 12, 18, 18, 24)' and y has '7.357' if that helps.

Comment: You might also be having issues with the locator not being set up for dates.

Comment: ax = plt.axes(ylim=(0, 8))
ax.get_xaxis().set_major_locator(matplotlib.dates.AutoDateLocator())
ax.get_xaxis().set_major_formaterr(matplotlib.dates.AutoDateFormatter())       gets  AttributeError: 'XAxis' object has no attribute 'set_major_formaterr'

Comment: @Kevin There was an obvious typo in that line.

Comment: ax.get_xaxis().set_major_locator(matplotlib.dates.AutoDateLocator())
ax.get_xaxis().set_major_formatter(matplotlib.dates.AutoDateFormatter())
There is still something wrong with the second line .